# What type is a points vector in objective C

Tags: vector, objective-c++

I have the following declaration for a function and I don't know what I am doing wrong with regards to the type declaration:

```
//function is defined in the OpenCVWrapper.mm file .....no errors
+ (NSArray *)analysePoints:(std::vector<cv::Point> )pointsVector{
    .......
}

//error is in the OpenCVWrapper.h file
@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

+ (NSArray *)analysePoints:(NSMutableArray *)mutableArray:(std::vector<cv::Point>)pointsArray;
//red marker under the std
@end
```

I am getting the error "expecting type" for the vector. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to help you. Please copy  and paste the *exact* wording of  the message. Also, it would help if  we knew which files you were importing into this source file (that is, which headers). Also, what is the name of  your source file? Does it end in ".m" or ".mm", or something else?

Comment: just added information requested above. "Expected a type" is the error message.

Comment: sorry, just noticed that I deleted the NSMutableArray part to avoid confusion, but in the addition I did not delete it. So the first statement in .mm file is + (NSArray *)analysePoints:(NSMutableArray *)mutableArray : (std::vector<cv::Point> )pointsArray{....

Comment: By  "exact wording of the message" I mean the *entire* message - the file name, the text it's complaining about and everything else. It makes a difference  to helping you. Also, you haven't told us which headers you're including. Finally, the spacing between arguments in your header file is ambiguous to the compiler. There should be a space between `mutableArray` and the `:(std::vector<cv::Point>)pointsArray` part. The compiler should warn you about that, though the warning may be masked by the error.

Comment: can I ask a different question? What is the type of a vector? The compiler asks for a type and I seem to not provide the right type. The above is really all there is (no additional info about the error message) except that I am also including #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>. 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>.    Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the solution through user11118321 input to look at the bigger picture. I am using this set up in a swift app that uses openCV through a bridging header. It is actually not possible to import or use a vector in swift.